# Sufficient condition for a smooth manifold $M$ to be compact.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, compactness, smooth-manifolds, geodesic

I am self-studying the book *Differential Geometry and Topology* of Keith Burns & Marian Gidea and  I got stuck on Exercise 4.8.12 (p.169):

> Suppose that for every smooth Riemannian metric on a manifold $M,$ $M$ is complete. Show that $M$ is compact.

I believe that I should use the following statement:

A geodesic $\gamma:[0,+\infty)\to M$ is called a ray if it minimizes the distance between $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(s)$ for all $s \in [0,+\infty).$ Show that if $M$ is complete and non-compact, then there is a ray leaving from every point in $M$.

I thought of using a proof by absurd. If $M$ was not compact then for every Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ there would be a geodesic ray at every point. From this point on I got stuck; I only have a vague idea on how to proceed: given a metric $g$ on $M$ I could modify $g$ into a metric $\tilde{g}$ so that $(M,\tilde{g})$ has a point $p$ without a geodesic ray. Furthermore, I believe the lack of compactness of $M$ has to play a role in the definition of $\tilde{g}.$

Comment: Do you already know how to change a metric but keep the conformal class? Did Burns by any chance explain how to construct a complete metric in the given conformal class? Lastly, try to solve this in case your manifold is the real line.

Comment: @MoisheKohan no he does not mention anything related to conformal classes. If I am not mistaken, one way to change the metric keeping in the same conformal class is by multiplying the metric by a positive smooth function, isn't it?

Comment: That's right. It does not change the conformal class.

Comment: @MoisheKohan so your hint is to find a suitable smooth function to modify the metric but not to change the conformal class. Thanks, I will make another attempt!